# troubles with my 2 dimensions tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

[SUPER CANVAS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me0eV.png)

I am using a 2 dimensions tree in order to contain my shapes. For my issue, let's just focus on the X axis.

So I am ordering my tree according to the X value of my items. Let's say B is the first shape, then we add A to my tree. My algorithm works like this (I wrote it much shorter because we dont really care about this part):

```
if(A.X > C.X)
    if(A.LeftChild   == null)
        A.LeftChild = C
    else
        go to A.LeftChild   
else
    if(A.RightChild  == null)
        A.RightChild = C
    else
        go to A.RightChild
```

Now, here is my issue. As u can see there is a red point on my draw. That's the place where I click in order to select the D item, but it doesn't work because the algorithm works like this:

```
if(B.X > Mouse.X)
go to C
else if (B.X < Mouse.X)
go to A
etc...
```

So it goes to the node C which doesn't contain D, so at the end it never finds the D item.

I came up with two solutions but both of them are pretty shitties according to me.

**1st solution :** To move all the biggest items at the top of my tree. So each time, I am resizing or adding an item, I have to check if it contains other items on both axis.

[solution 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUNrl.png)

**2nd solution :** To put the D item as the child of the A and C nodes. For this, I check the max X of my shapes as well (this algo is a simplified one too, I am pretty sure some parts are missing too).

[solution 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5icZ.png)

```
Add(newItem){
if(currentNode.minX > newItem.MinX && currentNode.maxX < newItem.MaxX){
    if(currentNode.LeftChild     == null)
        currentNode.LeftChild = new Item
    else
        go to currentNode.LeftChild 
    if(currentNode.RightChild    == null)
        currentNode.RightChild= new Item
    else
        go to currentNode.RightChild    
}else if(currentNode.minX < newItem.MinX){
    if(currentNode.LeftChild     == null)
        currentNode.LeftChild = new Item
    else
        go to currentNode.LeftChild 
}
```

Do u have better solutions to suggest me??? Because I am not satisfied with both of them.

Thank u very much!

Answer (score 0):

A simple algorithm for the

"what did I hit with a click?"

problem is rendering with a different color per shape into a buffer, and reading back the color under mouse point mapped onto that buffer.

Answer (score 0):

**@decltype_auto**

Yep but I don't want to use a classic iterative algorithm to know what did I hit with a click. Because if I have 25 000 items it would probably take a lot of time to find the selected item. That's why, I am using this algorithm :

```
if(currentNode.item.contains(mouse.position){
    currentNode.item.selected = true;
}
if(currentNode.minX < mouse.X)
    go to currentNode.LeftChild
else if(currentNode.minX > mouse.X)
    go to currentNode.RightChidld
```

Using this algo allows me to find an item faster. Nevertheless, it doesn't work well enough. That's why, I am asking for other ideas.

Besides, thank you for your answer.

Comment: One doesn't search en suite in the color codes. 25000 < 2**16 so a 16 bit color encoding suffices and thus in < 64K * ptr_size you can store a perfect hash for that, which provides O(1) lookup complexity.

Comment: @decltype_auto I think what ITbob is looking for is all about how to optimize the re-balancing process of the 2 dimensions KD Tree.
Everybody is aware of the O(1) lookup for hash-tables and dictionaries, IMO what does matter to him here is actually the 2 dimensions interval re-balancing... (that is, not something based on a key-value or hashfunction related stuff).